# TypeError: common.ɵsetRootDomAdapter is not a function . Facing problem after serving ssr

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering

I want to serve my project on ssr, after installing all the dependecies and building the project with npm run build:ssr, it fails on npm run serve:ssr, the error that appears is :
common.ɵsetRootDomAdapter(new DominoAdapter());
^
TypeError: common.ɵsetRootDomAdapter is not a function

this is my config :

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.28
Node: 12.18.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                                    Version
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect                  0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-angular              0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer            0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-webpack              0.803.26
@angular-devkit/core                       8.3.26
@angular-devkit/schematics                 8.3.28
@angular/cdk                               8.2.3
@angular/cli                               8.3.28
@angular/flex-layout                       10.0.0-beta.32
@angular/material                          8.2.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter           9.2.2
@angular/platform-server                   10.1.3
@ngtools/webpack                           8.3.26
@nguniversal/express-engine                8.2.6
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader   8.2.6
@schematics/angular                        8.3.28
@schematics/update                         0.803.28
rxjs                                       6.4.0
typescript                                 3.5.3
webpack                                    4.39.2



 "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
        "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
        "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.7.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
        "@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.4.5-beta",
        "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.2",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.4.2",
        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.4.0",
        "@fullcalendar/list": "^4.4.0",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
        "@ngu/carousel": "^1.5.5",
        "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^8.2.6",
        "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^9.0.0",
        "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.13",
        "@types/history": "^4.7.3",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.35",
        "actioncable": "^5.2.4",
        "angular-calendar": "^0.28.16",
        "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
        "angularx-social-login": "^2.2.1",
        "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
        "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
        "date-fns": "^2.15.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
        "imagesloaded": "^4.1.4",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "nativescript-angular": "^10.0.0",
        "ng-animate": "^0.3.4",
        "ng-masonry-grid": "^1.3.0",
        "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
        "ng2-trim-directive": "^2.3.4",
        "ng5-slider": "^1.2.4",
        "ngx-color-picker": "^9.1.0",
        "ngx-dropzone": "^2.2.2",
        "ngx-float-button": "^1.0.0",
        "ngx-gallery": "^5.10.0",
        "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.4",
        "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.0.0",
        "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^2.1.1",
        "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.4",
        "ngx-spinner": "^8.1.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
        "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
        "tslib": "^1.10.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
    },
```

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(DIST_FOLDER, 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
global['Event'] = win.Event;
global['KeyboardEvent'] = win.Event;
global['MouseEvent'] = win.Event;
global['Event']['prototype'] = win.Event.prototype;
global['document'] = win.document;
// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('../dist/browser/index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the version "@angular/platform-server": "^10.1.3" to "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.14" in your package.json and run the command npm install. After that npm run build:ssr and npm run serve:ssr.